# Interupt a while-loop using a global hotkey in Python

Tags: python, opencv, while-loop, global-hotkey

I'm currently stuck on a programme that I'm writing in Python using CV2. The programme works with a while loop, which is triggered by a hotkey. I want to use the hotkey to toggle the programme/ loop on and off. The problem I'm having is that since the hotkey function is outside the while loop, it is no longer recognized while the loop is running (at least I think that's what the problem is) and I can therefore no longer toggle the loop off.

This is the code i'm currently working with:

```
import PIL.ImageGrab
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
import pyautogui
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key

COMBINATIONS = [
    {keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.KeyCode(char="a")},
    {keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.KeyCode(char="A")}
    ]
isRunning = False

current = set()

def test():
    print("This is a seccessful test")

def templateMatch():

        imgGrab = PIL.ImageGrab.grab().save("background.jpg", "JPEG")
        time.sleep(2) #set interval here
        imgBGR = cv2.imread("background.jpg")
        imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(imgBGR, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        template = cv2.imread("template.png", 0)
        width, height = template.shape[::-1]

        res = cv2.matchTemplate(imgGray, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
        threshold = 0.99
        loc = np.where(res >= threshold)

        for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
            print(pt)

        pyautogui.click(pt[0]+width/2, pt[1]+height/2)

def on_press(key):
              if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
                     current.add(key)
                     if any(all(k in current for k in COMBO) for COMBO in COMBINATIONS):
                         global isRunning
                         isRunning = not isRunning
                         print(isRunning)
                         while(isRunning):
                             templateMatch()                            

def on_release(key):
           if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
               current.remove(key)

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
           listener.join()
```

Comment: The problem is having an infinite loop inside the `on_press` event handler. That way you block the keyboard listener, so it can't handle any more keypresses, while you're forever looping (since there's nothing that could change the value of `isRunning`). This needs to be redesigned.

Comment: Thanks @Hari_Sheldon for your quick response. Could you possibly elaborate on why generator functions would help with my issue? After reading your linked post, I still don't quite get the idea.

Comment: Thank you @DanMašek for your answer aswell. Would I rather put the loop inside the templateMatch function?

Comment: Neither the loop, nor the call to `templateMatch` should really be in the event handlers. Ideally those are short and just signal the code doing the processing. You could do the work on the main thread (in the `with`, before the `join()`) or even on a separate worker thread.

Comment: @DanMašek sorry for wasting your time, but I'm still stuck with my problem, even after writing the execution in the `with` part. If you have some spare time, could you possibly give me an example of what you mean?